# Redirect to previous page wherever it is directed to the login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

I'm using Rails 3.2 and Authlogic. I have the following code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private

  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url
  end

  def redirect_back_or_default(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session[:return_to] = nil
  end
end

class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController  
  before_filter :require_no_user, :only => [:new, :create]
  before_filter :require_user, :only => :destroy

  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
    @header_title = "Login"
  end

  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
      flash[:success] = "Login successful!"
      redirect_back_or_default root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_user_session.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Logout successful!"
    redirect_back_or_default root_url
  end
end
```

This code is quite generic. When we use the `before_filter`:

```
  before_filter :require_user, :only => [:new, :edit, :update, :create]
```

It will automatically `store_location` and redirect us back to the proper page. However, how do I do this:

1. I'm in `posts/1` which doesn't `require_user`.
2. I click the login link on my top navigation bar.
3. It shows the login page.
4. Once login, I will be redirected back to `posts/1` instead of the `root_url`.

Comment: What's the problem here? I assume a successful login does *not* redirect back to `session[:return_to]`?

Comment: `session[:return_to]` only stores when a `require_user` is called. I wanna store every url before `login` page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a `store_referrer_location` to make it work:

```
# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private

  def store_referrer_location
    session[:return_to] = request.referrer
  end
end

# user_sessions_controller.rb
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    store_referrer_location if session[:return_to].blank?
    @user_session = UserSession.new
    @header_title = "Login"
  end

  ...

  def destroy
    store_referrer_location if session[:return_to].blank?
    current_user_session.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Logout successful!"
    redirect_back_or_default root_url
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a direct call to `store_location` in the sessions controller `new` action.

```
# user_sessions_controller.rb
def new
  store_location if session[:return_to].blank?
  @user_session = UserSession.new
  @header_title = "Login"
end
```

This will first check for an existing `return_to` pair in the sessions hash. You don't want to overwrite it in case, for example, a user is redirected to the `new` action because of a bad password.

This will also skip `store_location` if it was already called from `require_user`.

After a successful redirect, you have to [delete](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-delete) the `return_to` pair from the sessions hash; setting it to *nil* is not enough:

```
  # application_controller.rb
  def redirect_back_or_default(default)
    redirect_to(session.delete(:return_to) || default)
  end
```