# Save parameters between actions Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, persistence

I have a controller, named OrdersController. And db table "Orders" with information about shop orders.
In a index page (localhost/) I must show two buttons: today orders and orders in range (with two inputs).

First button should open a page with list of orders, created today (Date.current for example).
Second button should open a page with list of orders, that was created in date range, specified in the input .

When I click on some order the details page is opens for it. There I can edit some fields of order and click "Update" button (it must update **@order** and redirect to (!)previous page - if it is today orders, then open a todays order. If it is a orders in a date range - then show orders created in range that was specified).

The question: what is the best practise to pass parameters between actions? How can I say to my "update" action where to redirect_to (to page with today orders or to page with orders in range) after updating? It must be a hiiden tag with params[:start_date] or something else?

The same is for the "back" button on the Order details page. It must return to the previous page (saving all the parameters that was passed for). I was thinking about

```
link_to 'Back', :back
```

But I heared it's not a good solution.

Thx!

Comment: If the "parameters" are simple query string params in the URL, you could use the session to store the previous location and then redirect the user to that after update.  There are a number of SO questions related to this.  Here's one example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630652/redirect-to-previous-page-wherever-it-is-directed-to-the-login-page

Answer (score 1):

I have used it in `redirect_to` not in `link_to`.

`:back` is a good option in `update` or `create` actions, since redirect is done through a GET, so when you POST to `orders` or PUT to `orders/1` I suppose you will redirect user to `orders/new` or `orders/1/edit`.

But as you want to redirect to `/orders` maintaining your search page, your hidden field makes more sense, in `app/views/orders/_form.html.erb` inside the form block:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :redirect_url, request.referrer %>
```

Then in your orders_controller in update or create actions:

```
redirect_to params[:redirect_url]
```

Comment: Oh, yes :) I didn't think in that way. Thanks!